# How to send FCM token to server?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please help me figure this out. All the FCM docs neglect this part (which makes me think it's something simple that I *should* know, but I'm new to coding backends). I need to send the FCM FIRInstanceID token to my server (I use Google Cloud, writing in Node.js). When it gets to the server, it is decoded (according to the FCM docs). But how do I get it to the server? The video says, "This is kinda up to you." This is absurd to me, having no clue how to send anything to a server, let alone a token. What's the code for this? Do I need to structure the token in a certain way? How do I know what address to send the token? (www.google.myserver.com???). I would deeply appreciate any help. I've spent so many days trying to figure this out.

More generally, if anyone has set up FCM + iOS + Firebase + Google Cloud and can explain it to me that would be amazing too (there are no resources for this online!) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the FIRInstanceID to your server only if you plan to use it in the future (like to send a message to a specific device).

If you only want to use topics you can skip this part.

To send the token to your server you can use different ways like:

1. use Firebase Database to store the value in the backend database
2. implement a http endpoint (like in Node.js) that can receive and store the token, than call the http endpoint from your app with the token (and maybe more information like the username of the user and some form of authentication to protect your backend)

Comment: What would be the structure of the data in the backend server if I was going to need to send notifications to individual devices? That's what I'm doing. So, I would store the tokens of each user-device in the backend? One thing that is tricky for me to understand: how is the data in the database accessed / used? (I am totally familiar with Firebase Database, but not familiar with a server-side database).